# What temporal phrase is being used here?

Tags: dates

Disclaimer * I do not speak or read French *

In researching French Canadian church records for burials, I have come across a volume that uses the same phrase as part of the standard script where other volumes have provided a relative temporal reference (e.g., décéde le hier jour). I have spent hours trying to figure out what this phrase means but between the cursive script and my lack of knowledge, I just can't figure it out. I take the meaning to be a non-specific phrase, like "died in recent days". I have four examples below that all should say the same thing (but the third one may be a variation); "décéde [something] jours". Can anyone give me a hint as to what the [something] is?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to me like **décédée depuis deux jours** for the first and second ones, **décédée depuis quatre jours** for the third one, and **décédé depuis deux jours** for the last one.

The meaning would be "dead since two days" (for a female), "dead since four days" (for a female) and "dead since two days" (for a male), respectively.

Comment: Insofar as I can make them out, I agree. :) (I feel strongest about the third one...) Since the asker mentioned that s/he doesn't speak French, it might be good to provide a translation in this answer: "Passed away two/four days ago."

Comment: How did you read that? Oo'

Comment: @Mistalis I have sloppy handwriting myself ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!! "depuis" was the word I couldn't figure out. This is a big help to me :)